# Integrals involving sum of differentials.

Tags: calculus

What would be the solution to such an integral:
$$\int xdx + xdxdx+dxdxdxdx $$
in case of are of a ring we do:
$$\int \pi(r+dr)^2-\pi r^2 $$
$$=> \int 2\pi rdr +drdr $$
Here we neglect drdr but why ?

Comment: Is this your idea, or did you find that somewhere?

Comment: As presented, I would say the integral doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Please add it fast, because your question at the moment is not clear at all, so it will get downvotes and lose visibility.

Comment: done I was late.

Comment: That has to do with integration in general : when you think of what $drdr$ and so on mean in terms of a partition and upper/lower sums, it is easy to see that if there's more than one $dr$ then such terms will go to zero as the partition gets finer. The idea is that one $dr$ makes the term bounded, and the other $dr$s are going to $0$, so the product of something bounded, and something going to $0$, also goes to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE.
[image]I think you are working on a ring from a circle with a radius of $r$ and increasing by $\Delta r$. $$f(r)=\pi r^2\\
\Delta f= f(r+\Delta r)-f(r)
\\=\pi(r+\Delta r)^2-\pi r^2\\=2\pi r \Delta r +(\Delta r)^2$$ usually $\Delta r \to 0 $ or very small, so $(\Delta r)^2$ tends to $0$.

so $ \Delta f\sim 2\pi r \Delta r +\underbrace{(\Delta r)^2}_{\to 0}$  .

Remark:IF we have double integration then $dxdy$ means. for example $$\int\int f(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2$$ this is meaningful.

Comment: if it was  3drdr or 3(dr)^2 would you still say it is zero?

Comment: I mean when 2dr will not be zero integration of dr will not be zero how come we take drdr as zero